# Dropdown close on click (mobile devices)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, prestashop-1.6

I have a dropdown menu that works perfect on desktop web browsers, but in mobile devices it open normally but when I click on some link the dropdown disapear without redirect to the link.

```
<li class="menu-zapatos-mujer parent dropdown aligned-fullwidth">
        <a href="http://calzadoslomas.com/tienda/412-senora" class="dropdown-toggle has-category" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="menu-title">Zapatos Mujer</span><b class="caret"/>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-sub dropdown-menu">
```

This is the web I'm solving this issue > http://calzadosplusultra.com/

It's using bootstrap.js v3.0.0

I have checked also other threads similar to this but so far there is not solution, and I think there should be something more to do before use a collapse option.

Thanks.

Comment: Since your each category have  some sub-category so the code is like :- on click of main category in mobile menu,the sub-menu will open under it and when you click on any sub-category,page refreshed and that category data will comes out. And this is working fine and it's a correct behavior also

Comment: @Anant it's working almost normal, the links are not working, and the dropdown is closed/reset, that is the main problem.